# Evaluate : $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(\sec ^2 x)\sec^2x }{(\sec ^2 x+1)\tan x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to evaluate :

$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(\sec ^2 x)\sec^2x \mathrm dx}{(\sec ^2 x+1)\tan x}$$
By substituting $x\to \frac{\pi}{2} - x$ , I get :

$$I =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(\csc^2 x)\csc^2x \mathrm dx}{(\csc ^2 x+1)\cot x}$$

But I do not know how to proceed with this. I also tried the substitution $\tan x = u$ which transform $I$ to :

$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(u^2 +1)\mathrm du}{u^3+ 2u}$$

But still I cannot proceed further from here because I have never solved such type of integrals with the limited techniques I know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I claim that
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(\sec ^2 x)\sec^2x \mathrm dx}{(\sec ^2 x+1)\tan x} = \frac{\pi^2}{16}.$$

We start with the substitution $\sec^2x = u$ to obtain
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(\sec ^2 x)\sec^2x \mathrm dx}{(\sec ^2 x+1)\tan x} = \frac{1}{2}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln(u)}{(u+1)(u-1)}\,du = \frac{1}{2}\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln(u)}{u^2-1}\,du.$$
Next make the substitution $u = 1/t$ to obtain
$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln(u)}{u^2-1}\,du = -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{1} \frac{\ln(t)}{1-t^2}\,dt$$
We can expand $1/(1-t^2)$ by its geometric series to get
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(t)}{1-t^2} = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1t^{2n}\ln(t)\,dt.$$
Making the substitution $y=-\ln(t)$ yields
$$\int_0^1t^{2n}\ln(t)\,dt = -\int_0^{\infty}ye^{-(2n+1)y}\,dy.$$
Then $(2n+1)y = \alpha$ yields
$$-\int_0^{\infty}ye^{-(2n+1)y}\,dy = -\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\int_0^{\infty}\alpha e^{-\alpha}\,d\alpha = -\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2},$$
where we evaluated the last integral using integration by parts. Hence
$$-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1t^{2n}\ln(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}.$$
The last sum has a [well known value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) of $\pi^2/8$, which means
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(\sec ^2 x)\sec^2x \mathrm dx}{(\sec ^2 x+1)\tan x} = \frac{\pi^2}{16}.$$
This agrees numerically with what desmos tells me.

Answer (score 6):

Start from where the OP stuck, Let $$F(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+au^2)}{u(u^2+2)}du\Longrightarrow F'(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{u}{(u^2+2)(1+au^2)}du$$

So $F(0)=0$, then let $t=u^2$

$$F'(a)=\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(t+2)(1+at)}dt=\frac{\ln(2a)}{2(2a-1)}$$
We get
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+u^2)}{u(u^2+2)}du=F(1)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(2a)}{2(2a-1)}da$$

Let $x=2a$

$$F(1)=-\frac14\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}dx-\frac14\int_1^2 \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac14\int_1^2 \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}dx$$

Let $t=x-1$

$$F(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{24}+\frac14\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}dt$$

Integration by part, we get

$$F(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac14\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(t)}{1+t}dt=\frac{\pi^2}{24}+\frac{\pi^2}{48}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$$

Comment: N.b. there's a slightly delicate issue here in the computation of $F'(a)$, namely that the denominator of the expression derived for $F'(a)$ has a singularity at $a = \frac12$. This singularity is, however, removable.

Comment: MathFail, could you explain how you get that $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x-1}\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi^2}6\;?$ And how do you get that $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x+1}\mathrm dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\;?$

Comment: Expand $\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}x^k$ and compute the integral like $$\sum_{k=0}\int_0^1 x^k\ln x dx=\sum_{k=0}\frac{-1}{(k+1)^2}$$ @Angelo

Comment: MathFail, in this case, if you still need expand terms into series, you could avoid inserting a new parameter $a$ and just calculate the OP’s integral by expanding terms into geometric series. It is what BBBBBB did in his answer.

Comment: BBBBBB re-do the calculation from the very beginning by using a different substitution. What I did is to take where the OP stuck and proceed. @Angelo

Comment: MathFail, if you avoid inserting a new parameter and let $t=\dfrac1{u^2+1}$ where the OP stuck, you can get the result of the integral just by expanding a term into a geometric series. For that reason, I think that in this case inserting a new parameter just makes the solution longer.

Comment: Right, this can shorten the steps. Thank you for mentioning this. @Angelo

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell that why the other substitution by another user made it diverging ?

Answer (score 6):

Let $u=\ln(\sec^2x)$ and then
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(\sec ^2 x)\sec^2x \mathrm dx}{(\sec ^2 x+1)\tan x}\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^{\infty} \frac{ue^u}{e^{2u}-1}\mathrm du=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{ue^{-u}}{1-e^{-2u}}\mathrm du\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty ue^{-(2n+1)u}\mathrm du\\
&=&\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks. Is that an Arithmetico Geometric series in last you utilised ?

Comment: It is not arithmetic/geometric series. It is Riemann Zeta function with $s=2$.

Comment: Sorry , I meant last second not last. Typo

Comment: It is geometric series.

Answer (score 6):

Utilize $ \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\tan y}{\tan^2y+a^2}dy =\frac{\ln a}{a^2-1}$ with $a^2=\sec^4x$ to integrate
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln(\sec ^2 x)\sec^2x}{(\sec ^2 x+1)\tan x}dx\\
=&\ \frac12 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{\tan y \tan x \sec^2x}{\tan^2y+\sec^4x}dy\ dx
=\frac12 \int_0^{\frac\pi2}y \ dy=\frac{\pi^2}{16}
\end{align}

Comment: I haven't learnt double integrals yet. But thanks for the another solution :)

Answer (score 4):

We make the substitution $x \mapsto \cos^2x$ to get

$$
I := \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln\left(\sec^{2}x\right)\sec^{2}x}{\left(\sec^{2}x+1\right)\tan x}dx=-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln\left(\cos^{2}x\right)\cot x}{1+\cos^{2}x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{x^{2}-1}dx.
$$

Let $f(z) = \displaystyle\frac{\log z}{z^2-1}$ where $\operatorname{arg}(z) \in (-\pi,\pi]$ and the branch cut is on the negative real axis. The series expansion of $f(z)$ centered at $z=1$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}-\frac{z-1}{2}+\frac{5}{12}\left(z-1\right)^{2}+O\left(\left(z-1\right)^{3}\right)$, which tells us $z=1$ is a removable singularity.

Next, we traverse along the following contour in the positive direction.

[image]

Cauchy's Residue Theorem allows us to write

$$
0 = \left(\int_{r}^{1}+\int_{\Gamma}^{ }+\int_{i}^{ir}+\int_{\gamma}^{ }\right)f(z)dz.
$$

Equating the real part on both sides gives us

$$
0 = \int_{r}^{1}f(z)dz+\Re\int_{\Gamma}^{ }f(z)dz+\Re\int_{i}^{ir}f(z)dz+\Re\int_{\gamma}^{ }f(z)dz.
$$

We evaluate each contribution and take $r \to 0^+$ below.

---

$$
\begin{align}
I_2 &:= \Re\int_{\Gamma}^{ }f(z)dz \\
&= \Re\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\log\left(e^{i\theta}\right)}{\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{2}-1}d\left(e^{i\theta}\right) \\
&= \Re\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{ie^{i\theta}}{e^{2i\theta}-1}\log\left(e^{i\theta}\right)d\theta \\
&= \Re\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\csc\theta}{2}\left(\ln\left|e^{i\theta}\right|+i\operatorname{arg}\left(e^{i\theta}\right)\right)d\theta \\
&= \Re\frac{i}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\theta\csc\theta d\theta \\
&= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
I_{3} &:= \Re\int_{i}^{ir}\frac{\log z}{z^{2}-1}dz \\
&= \Re\int_{1}^{r}\frac{\log\left(iy\right)}{\left(iy\right)^{2}-1}d\left(iy\right) \\
&= \Re i\int_{r}^{1}\frac{\log\left(iy\right)}{y^{2}+1}dy \\
&= \Re i\int_{r}^{1}\frac{\ln\left|iy\right|}{y^{2}+1}dy-\Re\int_{r}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{arg}\left(iy\right)}{y^{2}+1}dy \\
&= -\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{r}^{1}\frac{1}{y^{2}+1}dy \\
&\to -\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y^{2}+1}dy \\
&= -\frac{\pi^{2}}{8} \\
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
I_4 &:= \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz \\
&= \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}\frac{\log\left(re^{i\phi}\right)}{\left(re^{i\phi}\right)^{2}-1}d\left(re^{i\phi}\right) \\
&= ir\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{i\phi}\log\left(re^{i\phi}\right)}{1-r^{2}e^{2i\phi}}d\phi \\
&= ir\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{i\phi}\left(\ln\left|re^{i\phi}\right|+i\operatorname{arg}\left(re^{i\phi}\right)\right)}{1-r^{2}e^{2i\phi}}d\phi \\
&= ir\ln r\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{i\phi}}{1-r^{2}e^{2i\phi}}d\phi-r\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\phi e^{i\phi}}{1-r^{2}e^{2i\phi}}d\phi \\
&\to  i\left(0\right)\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{i\phi}}{1-0^{2}e^{2i\phi}}d\phi-0\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\phi e^{i\phi}}{1-0^{2}e^{2i\phi}}d\phi \\
&= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$

---

Hence,

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= \lim_{r \to 0^+}I_1 + 0 -\frac{\pi^2}{8} + 0 \\
\implies I &= \frac{\pi^{2}}{16}\\
\end{align}
$$

and we're finished!

Comment: Thanks , although all went above my head :) Please check my recent question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4718584/1020656

Comment: @An_Elephant Sure, I'll check it out. Just know that the comments section is meant for questions/improvements, and I prefer that people send other questions/requests/whatnot through my Discord or email.

Comment: Okay thanks. Anyway, I found that my question was a duplicate and what I did was just a re-discovery.

Answer (score 2):

$$\newcommand{dilog}[1]{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(#1\right)}
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{\ln\left(\sec^2x\right) \sec^2x}{(\sec ^2 x+1) \tan x} \, dx \\
&= \frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x(x+2)} \, dx \tag1 \\
&= \frac12 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x(x+2)} \, dx + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac1x+1\right)}{\frac1x\left(\frac1x+2\right)} \, \frac{dx}{x^2}\right) \tag2 \\
&= \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x(x+2)} \, dx - \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\frac x{x+1}}{2x+1} \, dx \\
&= -\frac{\ln2\ln3}4 - \frac{J\left(\frac13\right)+J\left(\frac12\right)}2 \tag3 \\
&= \ln\sqrt3 \operatorname{arcoth}3 + \ln\sqrt2 \operatorname{arcoth}2 - \ln\sqrt2 \ln\sqrt3 + \frac{\dilog{\frac12} - \dilog{-\frac12} + \dilog{\frac13} - \dilog{-\frac13}}4 \tag4 \\
&= \frac{\ln2 \ln3}4 + \frac12\dilog{\frac12} + \frac12\dilog{\frac13} - \frac18\dilog{\frac14} - \frac18\dilog{\frac19} \tag5 \\
&= \boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{16}} \tag6
\end{align*}$$

---

###### Steps

- $(1)$ substitute $x\mapsto\arctan\sqrt x$
- $(2)$ split up the integral at $x=1$ and substitute $x\mapsto\dfrac1x$ for $x\in[1,\infty)$
- $(3)$ integrate the first term by parts and substitute $\dfrac x{x+2}\mapsto x$ :
  $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x(x+2)} \, dx = -\frac{\ln2\ln3}2 - \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln \frac x{x+2}}{x+1} \, dx = -\frac{\ln2\ln3}2 - \int_0^{\tfrac13} \frac{\ln x}{1-x^2} \, dx \quad ;$$
  substitute $\dfrac{x+1}x\mapsto x$ in the second term :
  $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\frac x{x+1}}{2x+1} \, dx = \int_0^{\tfrac12} \frac{\ln x}{1-x^2} \, dx \quad ;$$
  and write in terms of the parameterized integral,
  $$J(a) := \int_0^a \frac{\ln x}{1-x^2} \, dx \qquad (0<a<1)$$
- $(4)$ evaluate $J(a)$ :
  $$\begin{align*}
  J(a) &= \frac12 \ln a \ln \frac{1+a}{1-a} - \frac12 \int_0^a \frac{\ln(1+x) - \ln(1-x)}x \, dx \tag{1$'$} \\
  &= \ln a \operatorname{artanh}a - \frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n+\frac1n\right) \int_0^a x^{n-1} \, dx \tag{2$'$} \\
  &= \ln a \operatorname{artanh}a - \frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^2} a^n \\
  &= \ln a \operatorname{artanh}a + \frac{\dilog{-a}-\dilog a}2 \tag{3$'$}
  \end{align*}$$
- $(5)$ duplication formula $\dilog x + \dilog{-x} = \frac12 \dilog{x^2}$
- $(6)$ combine MathWorld's identities $(9)$, $(25)$, and $(27)$ in the right amounts to eliminate the logarithms, e.g.
  $$\begin{align*}
  \dilog{\frac12} &= \frac{\pi^2}{12} - \frac{\ln^22}2 \\
  \dilog{\frac13} - \frac16 \dilog{\frac19} &= \frac{\pi^2}{18} - \frac{\ln^23}6 \\
  \dilog{\frac14} + \frac13\dilog{\frac19} &= \frac{\pi^2}{18} + 2\ln2 \ln3 - 2\ln^22 - \frac{2\ln^23}3 \\[2ex]
  \implies \color{red}{\frac{\ln2\ln3}4} &= -\frac{\pi^2}{144} + \frac{\ln^22}4 + \frac{\ln^23}{12} + \frac18 \dilog{\frac14} + \frac1{24} \dilog{\frac19}
  \end{align*}$$

---

###### Steps for $J(a)$

- $(1')$ integrate by parts
- $(2')$ exploit the Maclaurin series for both logarithms
- $(3')$ definition of [dilogarithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) a.k.a. [Spence's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function)

Comment: Thanks ! I will soon learn about dilogarithm and will try to simplify it. My initial guess was that dilogarithm is the function $\ln(\ln(x))$

Comment: No, not the same. $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$ is the function whose derivative is $-\dfrac{\ln(1-x)}x$. Anyway, mystery solved!